# Move mouse pointer to caret with shortcut (in Win8)?

Tags: autohotkey

OK, so here is the problem:

Is there a way to use a keyboard shortcut to move my mouse pointer to above the caret in a specific program on Windows 8?

I am trying to devise an AutoHotkey script to do something in my translation program (memoQ) and need to automatically move my mouse pointer to above my caret in order for it to work.

Michael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this, Not sure if it always works, have heard that the caret position inside browsers is unreliable. You might have to apply a little bias of a few pixels to get the mouse cursor positioned exactly.

```
#Persistent
CoordMode, Caret, Screen

^w::
    MovePosX:=A_CaretX +5  ; Adjust 5 pixels to the right of A_CaretX position
    MovePosY:=A_CaretY -10 ; Adjust 10 Pixels above A_CaretY position
    MouseMove, %MovePosX% , %MovePosY%
Return
```

Comment: Hi Robert, That almost works. It gets to just below the caret. How can I apply that bias you mentioned? I would need it to be a little bit higher . . .

Comment: Made some adjustments. See if this helps you. Groet, Robert

Comment: Wow, perfect! It works. My script now works in memoQ.